# How to append the Output of a command to temporary file

Tags: python, temporary-files

I have been trying to append my output of a command to a temporary file in python and later doing some operations. Not able to append the data to a temporary file. Any help is appreciated! My sample code as follows.

Getting the error like this.

> with open(temp1 , 'r') as f:
> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _TemporaryFileWrapper

```
import tempfile
import os
temp1 = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
os.system("echo Hello world | tee temp1")
with open(temp1 , 'r') as f:
    a = f.readlines()[-1]
    print(a)
```

Comment: [NamedTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) already returns the opened file-like object, no need to `open()` it again

Comment: `temp1` is a Python variable name, not a file name. The value of that variable has a `name` attribute that contains the actual file name.

Comment: even when i accessed through name attribute ```
with open(temp1.name , 'r') as f:``` , it is still not working. problem is with the appending/piping the data to a temporary file. Does this can be achieved in some other way?

Answer (score 1):

```py
import tempfile
import os

# Opening in update-text mode to avoid encoding the data written to it
temp1 = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("w+")
# popen opens a pipe from the command, allowing one to capture its output
output = os.popen("echo Hello world")

# Write the command output to the temporary file
temp1.write(output.read())

# Reset the stream position at the beginning of the file, if you want to read its contents
temp1.seek(0)
print(temp1.read())
```

Check out [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) for more powerful subprocess communication.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you're trying to do isn't right.  It appears that you are trying to have a system call write to a file, and then you want to read that file in your Python code.  You're creating a temporary file, but then your system call is writing to a statically named file, named `'temp1'` rather than to the temporary file you've opened.  So it's unclear if you want/need to use a computed temporary file name or if using `temp1` is OK. The easiest way to fix your code to do what I think you want is like this:

```
import os
os.system("echo Hello world | tee temp1")
with open('temp1' , 'r') as f:
    a = f.readlines()[-1]
    print(a)
```

If you need to create a temporary file name in your situation, then you have to be careful if you are at all concerned about security or thread safety.  What you really want to do is have the system create a temporary directory for you, and then create a statically named file in that directory.  Here's your code reworked to do that:

```
import tempfile
import os

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as dir:
    tempfile = os.path.join(dir, "temp1")
    os.system("echo Hello world /tmp > " + tempfile)
    with open(tempfile) as f:
        buf = f.read()

print(buf)
```

This method has the added benefit of automatically cleaning up for you.

UPDATE: I have now seen @UlisseBordingnon's answer.  That's a better solution overall.  Using `os.system()` is discouraged.  I would have gone a bit different of a way by using the `subprocess` module, but what they suggest is 100% valid, and is thread and security safe.  I guess I'll leave my answer here as maybe you or other readers need to use `os.system()` or otherwise have the shell process you execute write directly to a file.

Comment: making temp to 'temp1' will make the file as normal . I want to use the temporary file in this usecase. like store the output of a command to it and needs to do some operations on the data. does this can be achieved in other way?

Comment: I notice that you say you want to "append to" a file.  This suggests you will have a file that already exists and has something in it. None of the answers so far deal with this, including mine.  Did you really mean "write to" rather than "append to"?  If you really meant "append to", then you don't need to do any of this stuff, as the file already exists and so already determines the path you want to operate on.

Comment: I mentioned append but actually i meant for writing. If i want to store the result of a command in a temporary file and do the operations on it later.

Comment: do you have any suggestions on my usecase? i have just updated my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, you should use the `subprocess` module instead of `os.system`. However from `subprocess` you can use the most recent interface (and by most recent, I believe this was adding in Python 3.4) of [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run).

The neat thing about using `.run` is that you can pass any file-like object to `stdout` and the stdout stream will automatically redirect to that file.

```py
import tempfile
import subprocess

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("w+") as f:
    subprocess.run(["echo", "hello world"], stdout=f)
    
    # command has finished running, let's check the file
    f.seek(0)
    print(f.read())
    # hello world
```

Comment: This won't work, because you opened the temporary file with a "w" flag, which doesn't allow reading its contents. You have to use "w+" if you intend to read as well as write.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 3.5 or later (as with most of us), then use `subprocess.run` is better because you do not need a temporary file:

```py
import subprocess

completed_process = subprocess.run(
    ["echo", "hello world"],
    capture_output=True,
    encoding="utf-8",
)
print(completed_process.stdout)
```

## Notes

- The `capture_output` parameter tells `run()` to save the output to the `.stdout` and `.stderr` attributes
- The `encoding` parameter will convert the output from bytes to string

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your needs, if your print your output, a quickier way, but maybe not exactly what you are looking for is to redirect the output to a file, at the command line level
Example(egfile.py):

```
import os

os.system("echo Hello world")
```

At command level you can simply do:

```
python egfile.py > file.txt
```

The output of the file will be redirected to the file instead to the screen

Comment: The OP clearly wants to write to a file with a command execution and then read the result in the same bit of code.  This answer is useless as to a solution to that problem.